# Stream saved video in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, video-streaming

This is my `Video` Model

```
class Video(models.Model):
id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
saved_location = models.FileField(upload_to="videos/")

def __str__(self):
    return self.id
```

This is my `post` methods which saves video inside `media/videos`

```
class Video_api(APIView):
permission_classes=[AllowAny]
video_serializer = serializers.video_serializer
def post(self,request):
    try:
        video_data = self.video_serializer(data=request.data)
        video_data.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        data = video_data.validated_data

        video_instance = Video.objects.create(
            id = data.get('id'),
            saved_location = data.get('video')
        )
        video_instance.save()

        return Response({"success":True})
    except Exception as e:
        return Response({"success":False,"message":str(e)})
```

Now I want to stream the saved video inside the `media/videos` on get request. I don't want to download the video. I just want to stream the video when user performs get request. Please give me solution or any documentation related to it.

Comment: Just use normal html video element.